# Entity framework code first approach - table query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In CODE FIRST approach,

How to keep the identity columns as wihtout identity seeds (no auto increment) ?

My entity as follow:

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   ...

}
```

Also, how to do foreign key here ? I want to add foreign key for below object.
what are the properties i have to add into above product class ?

```
public class ProductType
{

   public int id { get; set; }
   ....

}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx), the default setting is

> If the type of the primary key property is numeric or GUID it will be
>   configured as an identity column.

You can change that by providing `DatabaseGenerated` attribute and set it as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`.

To have foreign key from `Product` to `ProductType` you only need to provide below collection on `ProductType` class, it will be automatically discovered by convention, EF will generate foreign key column `ProductType_Id` in `Products` table.

```
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

However, to have both navigation on both classes you can add below code on `Product` class.

```
public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
```

Here is the complete code of the classes.

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
public class ProductType
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, Is it like- To add FK into ProductType table, I hav to add `ICollection<Product>` into `ProductType` table and no need to add any property into `Product` table ? Another thing: addition of `ProductTypeId` and `Producttype` field into `Product` class is for which reason.. for which relation ?

Comment: @user3711357, 1. Yes. 2. With or without `ProductTypeId` and `ProductType` properties, the `Products` will have FK column to `ProductTypes`, both properties are used in the application so you can easily access `ProductType` from product instance.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for detail, just one last query, In Products , why do we keep two properties - `ProductTypeId` and `ProductType`. I mean, both property will be created into table ?

Comment: @user3711357, Both of them are simply navigations, from product instance, we can access `ProductType`by `product.ProductType`, from productType instance we can access all products underneath it by `productType.Products`, If you don't need to be able to access that way, you don't have to add both properties, having `Products` collection only already sufficient to create a referential integrity in the database.